# accessing python object list

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to retrieve a list of images in a directory, and store this list into a attribute of a class. But when i try to get the list from the object it appears empty.This is the class:

```
class Hunting(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=10) 
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    images = {}

    def __str__(self):
        res = ''
        for image in self.images:
            res = res+image
        return res

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.id
```

And then this is what i do to populate and read the list:

```
page = int(page)
huntings = Paginator(Hunting.objects.all(), 9)
images = {}
for hunting in huntings.page(page):
    dir_name = settings.IMAGES_ROOT+'\\theme1\\images\\cotos\\'+str(hunting.id)+'\\'  # insert the path to your directory
    path = os.path.join(settings.STATIC_URL, dir_name)
    print >>sys.stderr, '--PATH:' + path
    if os.path.exists(path):   
        print >>sys.stderr, '--LIST IMAGE HUNTING '+str(hunting.id)+'--'
        img_list = os.listdir(path)
        hunting.images=img_list
        print >>sys.stderr, hunting.images
for hunting in huntings.page(page):
    print >>sys.stderr, '*******hunting '+str(hunting.id)+':'
    print >>sys.stderr, hunting.images
```

So, when i am iterating the first time and printing the hunting.images list i got:

```
--LIST IMAGE HUNTING 2--
['1_tn.jpg', '2_tn.jpg', '3_tn.jpg', '4_tn.jpg']
--LIST IMAGE HUNTING 4--
['coto10.png', 'coto11.png', 'coto12.png']
```

But the second iteration, trying to get the list i stored before i get an empty list

```
*******hunting 2:
{}
*******hunting 4:
{}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what happened is that you call `huntings.page(page)` for both of the loops. The first loop you **did** assign the images to the result of `huntings.page(page)`, but then you didn't keep the result, so for the second loop you call `huntings.page(page)` again and you got the same initial result as before.

I'm not sure what you want to achieve here, but you need to get the return value first in a variable then update it:

```
# keep the return value in variable huntings
huntings = [for hunting in huntings.page(page)]
for hunting in huntings:
    # do your hunting.images = img_list

for hunting in huntings:
    print >>sys.stderr, hunting.images
```